# React state value not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to update the value of topicsVisited state by passing the value from variable named `topicsVisited`. However, its not updating the values. When user visits the end of the topic page it should push the topicID value to the array and that array value will be stored in localstorage and transferred to the state.

```
import {React, ReactDOM} from '../../../../build/react';

import SelectedTopicPageMarkup from './selected-topic-page-markup.jsx';
import NextPrevBtn from './next-prev-btn.jsx';

export default class SelectedTopicPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      topicPageNo: 0,
      total_selected_topic_pages: 1,
      topicsVisited: []
    };
  };
  navigateBack(topicPageNo) {
    if (this.state.topicPageNo > 0) {
      topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo - 1;
    } else {
      topicPageNo = 0;
    }
    this.setState({topicPageNo: topicPageNo});
  };
  navigateNext(totalPagesInSelectedTopic) {
    let topicPageNo;
    if (totalPagesInSelectedTopic > this.state.topicPageNo + 1) {
      topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo + 1;
    } else if (totalPagesInSelectedTopic == this.state.topicPageNo + 1) {
      let topicsVisited = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('topicsVisited')) || [];
      topicsVisited.push(parseInt(this.props.topicsID));
      localStorage.setItem("topicsVisited", JSON.stringify(topicsVisited));
      this.setState({topicsVisited: topicsVisited});
      console.log(this.state.topicsVisited);
      this.props.setTopicClicked(false);
    } else {
      topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo;
    }
    this.setState({topicPageNo: topicPageNo});
  };

  render() {
    let topicsID = this.props.topicsID;
    let topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.topicPageData.filter(function(topicPage) {
          // if condition is true, item is not filtered out
          return topicPage.topic_no === topicsID;
        }).map(function(topicPage) {
          let totalPagesInSelectedTopic = topicPage.topic_pages.length;
          return (
            <div>
              <div>
                <SelectedTopicPageMarkup headline={topicPage.topic_pages[0].headline} key={topicPage.topic_no}>
                  {topicPage.topic_pages[topicPageNo].description}
                </SelectedTopicPageMarkup>
              </div>
              <div>
                <NextPrevBtn moveNext={this.navigateNext.bind(this, totalPagesInSelectedTopic)} key={topicPage.topic_no} moveBack={this.navigateBack.bind(this, topicPageNo)}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }.bind(this))}
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Check this link : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html . Maybe forceUpdate will solve the updating issue

Comment: How do you determine hat it's not updated? Hopefully not through the console.log call.

Answer (score 2):

The [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) docs talk about two important things:

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

and

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

You might want to consolidate your two `setState` calls or use a callback to do the work you want to be done after the state change.

The callback would look something like:

```
this.setState({topicsVisited: topicsVisited}, function() {
    console.log(this.state.topicsVisited);
    this.props.setTopicClicked(false);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: This really looks like a solution, you should not make an operation call setState and in the next lines call setState again, cause it'll be processing the logic for find out what changed an re-render it. As a simple and really poor and dirty workaround you can use a timer to achieve this too, like wait for 2 seconds and call setState again, but you have no garanties that the page is re-rendered. Definitly a callback looks more elegant and is what the developers thought when building the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the right code this setState method/function, instead of trying to change the state variable directly?

```
this.setState({
  topicPageNo: 0,
  total_selected_topic_pages: 1,
  topicsVisited: []
});
```

Comment: Initially the state will return no value. Therefore i've set it as an empty array. Once a particular topic last page is visited when user click on next button it will push the topicID to the array and update the value in state and local storage.

Comment: Not in the constructor.